# jQuery Credit Card Validation in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to validate a credit card number in MVC, but it's letting the user submit the form regardless of whether the credit card input is valid, or even empty.

Here's what I'm trying, could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? This is at the base of my view.

in the view, obviously with extra syntax, formatting:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckoutCart", "Cart", FormMethod.Post, new {@id ="checkoutform"}))

 @Html.Label("Credit Card Number:")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelTransaction.CreditCard, new { @id = "creditcard" })



@section scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#checkoutform").submit(function () {
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                debug: true,
                success: "valid"
            });

            $("#checkoutform").validate({
                rules: {
                    creditcard: {
                        required: true,
                        creditcard: true
                    }
                }
            });

            if ($("#checkoutform").valid()) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        });
});


</script>
}
```

Comment: yeah, in the _Layout. The javascript console doesn't show any errors

Comment: Any reason you cant add the `[CreditCard]` attribute to the property?

Comment: I could add the CreditCard attribute, but I'd like to have it first checked on the client-side

Comment: `can't get it working` isn't a descriptive problem statement. Why are you intializing validation plugin inside submit handler?

Comment: Adding `[CreditCard]` **does** check it on the client side (assuming you have included `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`.). Otherwise your going to have to add the data-val attributes to indicate its a credit card

Comment: edited with a bit more clarity...I figured that it wouldn't matter where I initialise it, it's only used inside the submit handler. I'll try and put it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the jQuery validation requires you to input the name attribute, not the id attribute.

So the validation part should have been:

```
$("#checkoutform").validate({
            rules: {
                ModelTransaction.CreditCard: {
                    required: true,
                    creditcard: true
                }
            }
        });
```

This is problematic, because of the '.'

So my solution was to instead use:

```
$("#checkoutform").validate({
        });

        $("#ModelTransaction_CreditCard").rules("add", { required: true, creditcard: true });

        $("#ModelTransaction_PostCode").rules("add", { required: true });

        $("#ModelTransaction_Address1").rules("add", { required: true });
```